# Login successfull with wrong password in php

Tags: php, password-protection, login-script

Im creating a login page.
Below code is when user fills in both username & password input fields.

**But if I enter username as 'admin' and a wrong password, it still accepts it and redirects me to members page.**

Please note I have just started into PHP.

```
$input['user'] = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);
$input['pass'] = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $input['user'], md5($input['pass'] . $config['salt']));
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0)
    {
        //successful login/set session
        $_SESSION['username'] = $input['user'];
        header("Location: members.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $error['alert'] = "Error: Username/password incorrect!";
        include('views/v_login.php');
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Error: Could not prepare MySqli result.";
}
```

Comment: look at your 2nd line of code... ;)

Comment: Also, don't use MD5, it's broken.

Comment: FYI, 2nd line of code is to simulate a wrong password, user still authenticates

Comment: Use Sha1, it's far more secure than md5. You'll have to change your database field to a much longer one

Comment: @NicolásTorres I don't know about "far more" secure. It's marginally better, but still not great. Using the SHA-2 family of hashes, such as SHA-256, would be far preferable.

Comment: @Wiseguy of course, nothing lasts forever. Today is secure, tomorrow it's not. But it's more secure than the already cracked md5

Comment: thanks i fixed it. 2nd line should hjave been htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$input['pass'] = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Change to

```
$input['pass'] = htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Although, logically this error shouldn't let you in with a bum password, it should reject any attempt where the password isn't the same as the username

Comment: Just what I was about to post ^_^ `+1`

Comment: I bet that the username and password are the same :)

Comment: Yeah, that would have to be the case. The password for 'admin' would have to be 'admin', which is arguably a worse sin than using md5. ;-)

Comment: Good point, if the password for the 'admin' user is 'admin', then this *would* cause the OP's error (among other things :P)

Comment: thanks guys, id n pw = admin. This is my local test :) damm i do too many silly misstakes.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at it, this stuck out

Change:

```
$stmt->num_rows > 0
```

To:

```
$stmt->num_rows == 1
```

First, there is no description as to what your database looks like, so who knows how many results there are. Also, if you have 1 login per user, that result should only EVER include 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

just to update..
This is fixed now, it was my silly misstake username & password at top

```
$input['user'] = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);
$input['pass'] = htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Also, I fixed it with proper comparison inside IF ELSE condition, as

```
$stmt->num_rows != 0
```

Thanks to everyone :)